# Changing content of the <title> element with pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-content

## What i want

To change contents of html 'title' element by selecting it via '::before' pseudo-element and applying 'content' attribute to selection.

## Problem

I have a webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Some title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
  <p>Some paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css stylesheet:

```
title::before {
  content: "Text";
}
p::before {
  content: "Text";
}
```

I can't seem to be able to change content of the html 'title' element this way with css style, but it works with 'p' element.

I know there is good javascript libraries with good functions which can handle this easily, but i want to apply these changes to external webpage served in my webbrowser with custom userstyle.css.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

The title element isn't rendered on the viewport like other elements since it's in the head and not the body, so pseudo-elements aren't going to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Just press F12 find head tag. You will find that it's already hidden by default. You can Change the content by jQuery. $('title').text('you text here');