# How to capture document title using CSS string-set

Tags: css

This CSS

```css
h1 { string-set: chapter content(text) }
```

captures the content of the h1 tag.

This CSS

```css
title { string-set: book content(text) }
```

fails to capture the document title.

How do I reference the document title strictly using CSS (no js)? I always expected the second example to fail, yet the head is nevertheless part of the DOM and thus it is not entirely out of the question that such a thing might be possible.

Comment: Maybe this "helps": https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676148/5374294

Comment: I should probably extend the question. I understand why string-set doesn't work on the title which is not part of the document body. Yet it _is_ part of the DOM, and my knowledge of such things is far from complete enough to rule out the possibility that there is some way to reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Orry's comment, this can't be done. Technically this isn't a duplicate, but the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676148/5374294 also explains why there is no good answer to this question.

Arguably the inability to access document information merely because it doesn't participate in the rendering pipeline is a defect in all the browsers but that's an argument for the standards committee and wouldn't see a useful outcome inside five years even were it tabled today.

For my own purposes I have a workaround: I can do this in the code that generates the document and embed it in the body in a non-visible tag, but... ewww.

I did that, and it works.

```html
<style>
  span.hiddenTitle { string-set: book content(text); display: none; }
  span.getStringFromHiddenTitle::after { content: string(book); }
</style>

<span class="hiddenTitle">The text of the title</span>
<span class="getStringFromHiddenTitle"></span>
```

Note the above solution sketch did't work in browser for reasons I have yet to fathom. Nevertheless it's working fine in my larger project.

Answer (score -2):

```
h1::before { content: 'Chapter xxx'}
h1 { string-set: chapter content(before)}
h1::after { content: '.'; }
```

Comment: How is that supposed to capture the document title?